Efficient modular exponentiation for all 64-bit arguments
I'm trying to improve the performance of the following modular exponentiation function I wrote. I feel like there might be some way of leveraging the fact that it calculates the same 64-bit modulus n of a 128-bit unsigned integer many times, up to 128 times! I don't mind sacrificing some portability and using 128-bit integer types, and I'm targeting x86_64. Is there anything faster in the general case than exponentiation by squaring?
uint64_t modpowu64(uint64_t a, uint64_t e, uint64_t n) {
// Returns a^e mod n
  if (n == 0) return 0;
  if (a < 2) return a;
  unsigned __int128 res = 1;
  unsigned __int128 sq = a % n;
  while (e) {
    if (e & 1ULL) res = (res * sq) % n;
    sq = (sq*sq) % n;
    e >>= 1;
  }
  return res;
}

The function above works, so maybe this isn't the right forum. Should this be on Code Review instead?

In the general case the number of steps can be reduced by 'windowing' -- taking several exponent bits at a time, in big-to-little order (the reverse of yours) -- and this is commonly used for crypto algorithms like RSA and FFDH/DSA where exponents nowadays are 100s or 1000s of bits, but for 64 bits I don't think you get much and maybe not any savings. The other optimization for odd n (usual in crypto) is to use Montgomery representation with R=2^n (for even n I think you can scale down and then use some form of CRT)

@simon As with all "how to make faster" questions, best to first get functionality correct.  What result do you expect with modpowu64(1,e,1) and modpowu64(2,0,1).  This code returns 1.  I expect 0.

@chux I agree completely, In my program n=1 or 0 are both nonsense, but mod 1 is a thing so it should be 0.

How big is n in practice: can it really be any 64-bit values or actually smaller than that (max & average)? Supporting a sub-set can certainly help performance-wise (like signed integer sometimes). Btw, which compiler and flags do you use?

@JérômeRichard I was hoping for suggestions on improving the general case. In my current program, most of the time, n will be 60+ bits. I'm using gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0 and compile with -march=native -O3. I don't have AVX2 on this laptop which may make a difference, although I doubt it.

In my program, n is different on each call. Using Montgomery Multiplication is an interesting idea, but it requires the calculation of a modular inverse which is itself a costly operation which I don't think will help here unless there are lots of calls with the same n.

@SimonGoater When requesting faster code, consider also posting a test harness to assess the performance.  It makes candidate improvements less hypothetical and also provides some form of objective qualitative rating.  True that yours, mine on others' relative performance may vary, yet it is a good start.

I measured a modular inverse function and it was about 40% of the time taken for the above code, so there's hope that Montgomery might be beneficial here. I haven't yet got my head around Montgomery though to test it quantitatively.

I found a good resource here https://members.loria.fr/PZimmermann/mca/mca-0.2.pdf which describes in more detail, some of the optimisations mentioned by @dave_thompson_085. The Montgomery Form optimisation turned out to be awesome (up to 5x), but there are some further optimisations I could do sometime later.

After going to town on this a bit, I've found that for odd modulus n, using Montgomery Form was much more optimisable than I initially expected and can give significant performance improvements, 2-3x in my tests.
The key realisation was that the modular multiplications (u64 * u64) in the exponentiation function loop could be reduced to a 64 bit value which is congruent to the product mod n using only simple operations, avoiding many mod n operations as the intermediate results need not be reduced all the way to the interval [0, n-1].
The magic part is as follows, where ninv is the multiplicative inverse of n mod 2^64, and twoto64modn is as the name suggests, both of which only need to be calculated once per change of exponentiation modulus.
  unsigned __int128 prod128 = (unsigned __int128)ar*br; // 0 <= prod128 <= 2^128 - 2^65 + 1 
  uint64_t m = prod128 & 0xffffffffffffffffULL;         
  m *= -ninv;                                           // 0 <= m < 2^64
  unsigned __int128 mn128 = (unsigned __int128)m*n;     // 0 <= mn128 <= n*(2^64 - 1) && mn128 = -arbr mod 2^64
  unsigned __int128 sum = prod128 + mn128;              // 0 <= sum <= 2^128 + (n - 3)2^64
  unsigned __int128 max128 = (prod128 > mn128 ? prod128 : mn128);
  uint64_t sumu64 = sum >> 64;                          // 0 <= sum >> 64 <= 2^64 + (n - 3)
  // twoto64modn = 2^64 - xn for some x >= 1, so if sum overflowed, 
  // 0 <= sumu64 + twoto64modn <= (n - 3) + 2^64 - xn = 2^64 - (x-1)n - 3 < 2^64
  return sumu64 + (sum < max128)*twoto64modn;

The full code I've posted into a GitHub repo. here https://github.com/FastAsChuff/Fast-Modular-Exponentiation/tree/main

IIRC a % b for even b is just (a%2) + 2*((a/2) % (b/2)). E.g. 15 % 6 is 1 + 2*(7%3) so you can always transform even moduli to smaller odd moduli. This could also be done for other factors of b, but finding factors of 2 is easy (trailing zero bits)

@MSalters How do I get (a/2) % (b/2)? I only have a = x mod 2^k and a = y mod odd b.

I don't understand your problem? For a==15 in my example, a/2 is just 7. That's division by 2, utterly trivial.

Candidate improvement:
Avoid general 128 * 128 when 64 * 64 will do.
Help compiler understand that res and sq have 64-bit values.  These objects do not need to be 128-bit; only the multiplication and product needs to be 128 bit.  A good compiler can see (unsigned __int128) res * sq needs only a 64bit * 64bit ⟶ 128bit, whereas original code may not see that and instead perform the more time expensive 128bit * 128bit ⟶ 128bit.
  uint64_t res = 1 % n;  // Or the like to ensure a mod by 1 is 0 for `res`.
  uint64_t sq = a % n;
  while (e) {
    if (e & 1U) res = ((unsigned __int128) res * sq) % n;
    sq = ((unsigned __int128) sq * sq) % n;
    e >>= 1;
  }


Alternately, with C23, research if bool ckd_mul((unsigned __int128) *result, uint64_t a, uint64_t b); is available on your machine from include <stdckdint.h>.

Is zero test really needed?
if (n == 0) return 0; nice to prevent mod by 0, which is UB, but if speed is key, let such foolish calls fail with UB instead.
Also if (a < 2) return a; is not needed for rest of code to run correctly.  No need to waste time testing.  Drop it.
If anything, I would consider a test of n to see it is less than  2³² and add code to handle that special case much faster, yet OP wants general ideas.

All in all, these are only minor ideas and certainly the biggest chunk of time is spent doing the 128bit % 64bit ⟶ 64bit.

Parlor trick: test in the middle of the loop.
The case of e originally with the value  of zero, being a legitimate, yet an unusually use of this function, code does not need an optimal use of while (e) { ... } loop.
Also, sq = ((unsigned __int128) sq * sq) % n;, being somewhat expensive, is wasted work on the last iteration.
If an optimizing compiler does not see that useless work, we could help with:
#if 0
  while (e) {
    if (e & 1U) res = ((unsigned __int128) res * sq) % n;
    sq = ((unsigned __int128) sq * sq) % n; // Not needed in last iteration.
    e >>= 1;
  }
#else
  for(;;) {
    if (e & 1U) res = ((unsigned __int128) res * sq) % n;
    e >>= 1;
    if (e == 0) {
      break;
    }
    sq = ((unsigned __int128) sq * sq) % n;
  }
#endif


Proceed with caution.  Adjustments like this may eke out a few percent better performance, yet the code becomes harder to maintain.

A  simple alternative to uint64_t res = 1 % n; is uint64_t res = n > 1;.

Given that 0⁰ is mathematically undefined, I don't see any need to special-case res like that - just start with an unconditional 1.  0ⁿ will yield 0 for any n > 0, and we can be happy.  If we are imposed a definition, OP's approach of early exit for the special case is probably better.

I have to disagree with this answer (first part). (unsigned __int128) res * sq causes a cast of res to 128-bit and then a type promotion so both the multiplication and the division are still a 128-bit. The compiler can see that some value are 64-bit wide in a 128-bit integer but GCC and Clang cannot optimize that yet (far from being easy because of possible overflows).

Put it shortly, see on Godbolt: this does not really impact the generated code compare to the OP.

When I benchmarked this idea of keeping sq and res at 64 bit and casting to 128 before multiplying, I measured a small performance improvement of about 5-6%.

@TobySpeight "I don't see any need to special-case res" (which I think you refer to res = 1 % n is get the proper behavior with modpowu64(1,e,1) and modpowu64(a_more_than_1,0,1).

@All, key idea: many processors have a a_some_bit_width * a_some_bit_width --> product _some_twice_the_bit_width & run-time performance benefits when it is used rather than a general a twice_the_bit_width multiply. Some C libraries offer an extended function for that. Even using that performance is still get dominated by 128-bit % 64-bit. OP's 5% is reasonable. IAC, using unsigned __int128) res * sq) % n is unlikely to slow things significantly.

@JérômeRichard: There is no possible overflow in u64 * (uint128_t) u64 producing a u128 result.  In your Godbolt link, GCC uses a single mul for both the OP's and this modification. I guess it sees that res and sq have limited value-range due to the modulo so always does the optimization.  It does help for clang https://godbolt.org/z/dhMMK4e3a - its orig multiplies with mul for low x low and then the cross products are 2ximul + 2x add.  In chux's it has a missed-optimization in sq * sq, zeroing RSI before imul rsi, rsi as the high half, but avoids imul for res * sq
